# authentication user in ldap with cn=user

Tags: authentication, ldap

Good morning,

First thanks a lot for the helps.

I have a problem in my organization because there are legacy applications that to use an LDAP Server to authentication.

The problem is that the model to authenticate the applications this different. For example:

The applications to authenticate with the attribute cn=user (only this) and not cn=user,ou=XXX,dc=YYY,dc=WWW ie using the complete DN and the worst is that we have no codes of these applications.

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Sorry to have to ask, but what exactly is your question? You have legacy applications that need an LDAP. Fine, but doesn't that mean everything is still working? Or are you introducing these applications newly?

Comment: Somewhere in the configs for the applications or some layer in between (LDAP Realm perhaps) something is translating cn=user to a Fully Qualified name.  Microsoft Active Directory allows some Ambiguous Naming Resolution but cn=user is not one of them by default. Typically a service account would perform a search to find the entry cn=user (used as a searchFilter) locate the user and then perform the LDAP bind.